# Image upload anomaly

Tags: php, image-processing

Recently I changed servers and my images uploading/resizing script (https://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm) stopped working, error message "Local file doesn't exist." The only change there was since it worked - I changed from $filetoUpload[$i] to $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i].

Here's the script:

HTML

```
<form action="testupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload[0]" id="fileToUpload">
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload[1]" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>



<?php
// testupload.php
include('classes/class.images.inc.php');
$pictureslocation = "my images location/";

    for($i=0;$i<=1;$i++){
        if($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i] != "none" AND $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i] != ""){
              $handle =new upload($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]);
              if ($handle->uploaded) {
                    // Script doesn't get here but gives an error
              }else{
                echo 'error : ' . $handle->error; 
                // The error it gives here is "Local file doesn't exist."
              }
        }
  }
```

Just a simple upload script works without problems.